# PHP: file_get_contents is too slow

Tags: php

I'm trying to use ip-api.com/php 
but there's a very slow response on my server and I figured out that it is because of the file_get_contents

So basically, I have a pretty simple script (got from github I think)

```
function get_ip() {
        //Just get the headers if we can or else use the SERVER global
        if ( function_exists( 'apache_request_headers' ) ) {
            $headers = apache_request_headers();
        } else {
            $headers = $_SERVER;
        }
        //Get the forwarded IP if it exists
        if ( array_key_exists( 'X-Forwarded-For', $headers ) && filter_var( $headers['X-Forwarded-For'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 ) ) {
            $the_ip = $headers['X-Forwarded-For'];
        } elseif ( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $headers ) && filter_var( $headers['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 )
        ) {
            $the_ip = $headers['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {

            $the_ip = filter_var( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4 );
        }
        return $the_ip;
    }

$ip=get_ip();


$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
```

When it comes to

```
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
```

It freezes for around 1min.

Comment: maybe you hit a rate limit? does it work in a browser?

Comment: What you mean by rate limit? The situation appears in my new vps server, but the same website in another server at hostgator it works just fine.. I want to migrate to my new vps

Comment: just tried, they have a limit of 150 per minute, after pressing F5 150 times in Firefox, Firefox shows the wait animation, followed by a timeout error

Comment: Reason for this being slow has nothing to do with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @N.B. But why then everything works just fine on my old server ? anytime I execute that?

Comment: Did you read all the comments made here? You are rate limited. Karsten even tested it for you. The function `file_get_contents` has _nothing_ to do with this being slow.

Comment: This accesses another web server and waits for the response. An answer from that server is instant over here. Check your network, get a better connection, make sure that there's no trouble with accessing that server. "file_get_contents" waits until the response is complete or the query times out, whatever happens first. Instead of "file_get_contents", try using another way to access this which is better suited for accessing content over the network. Build a queue for these requests and separate processing these requests from the rest of the script with a "please wait" during the hold time.

Answer (score 3):

If you read their API you will see this:

> Deprecated Use JSON. Almost all PHP sites now support json_decode(),
>   and it's faster than unserialize()

The reference is [here](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php)

There you will also find how to do it with Json with an example you can leverage to get your point:

> To receive the response in JSON format, send a GET request to
>
> http://ip-api.com/json
>
> You can supply an IP address or domain to lookup, or none to use your
>   current IP address.

The reference is [here](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, http://ip-api.com/json didn't respond to the server and it takes much time. When I call from localhost it working fine.

Now I am using https://freegeoip.app/json/ and it's allowed up to 15,000 queries per hour by default.